# Boxplot including an "All" box

Tags: r, boxplot

Consider the dataframe

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(33),cat = gl(3,11))
```

When I plot a boxplot of `x` separated by each level of `cat` this is what I get

```
boxplot(df$x ~ df$cat)
```

[image]

Is it possible to include another box **in the same plot** showing **all** the values of `x`?

```
boxplot(df$x,xlab = "x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boxplot(x ~ cat, data = rbind(df, data.frame(x = df$x, cat = "all")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Jake! I just wanted to ask you if plyr is really necessary here (I've never used this package). After checking your answer I came up with the following df2 = rbind(df,data.frame(x=df$x,cat = "all")) and then I plot df2 instead of df. Is there a particular reason to use plyr in this case?

Comment: @Bernardo I thought I got an error about adding a new factor level to `cat`. But I just reran it with just `rbind` and it seems to work, so I edited the answer.